# how to show progress bar while fetching data from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, progress-bar

my activity is having list view only and it is programmed to fetch data from Firebase database but it every time it takes few seconds to display it on list view.
so what I want is to display progress bar until my list view is empty.

i don't know how it is possible kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnSuccessListener` this way

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Write was successful!
                // ...
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                // ...
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

May in the onSucesslistener from your queries you have a foreach or for, you may need to add percent to your progress bar, I'm kinda new to android so it may not work or have better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set `progressBarhorizontal.visibility = View.VISIBLE` in your activity and after finishing read data set `progressBarhorizontal.visibility = View.GONE`

Comment: Did my answer help you?@nir doshi